# Strange issue with Google Maps in Safari 5.0.4 and Leopard 10.5.8

Tags: macos, google-maps, safari, osx-leopard

DISCLAIMER: I am encountering this issue ONLY with the combination of Safari 5.0.4 and Mac OS X 10.5.8. Since I cannot expect many of you to be able to replicate this, Im thinking its worth a shot.

The issue involves jankiness with the way Google Maps loads locations on this page:

http://www.moonshine.com/findtheshine.php

Check out Austin, TX and San Diego locations.

I was thinking it could have to do something with map_canvas container, tried changing :relative to :absolute, even :fixed. No dice. I found a pattern too, it happens only with cities that have 15 or fewer locations attached to them.

Help?

Rishi

Comment: Can you post some screen shots?

Comment: Hey Alan, I can post a link to the image: http://yfrog.com/gzicyp. Thanks!

Comment: Alan, I found a solution, in my stylesheet, I removed margin:0 from *{margin:0, padding:0}

Comment: Actually I could use some advise on this. I know removing a CSS reset is a bad idea.